# CanCanCan: :read ability, but can update and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I have a nested resource in a namespace

```
namespace :myns do
  resources :dashboards do
    resources :advertisements
  end
end
```

I added check_authorization to the application controller and the controllers are configured

```
class Myns::DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :myns_dashboard, class: Myns::Dashboard
end

class Myns::AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :myns_dashboard, class: Myns::Dashboard
  load_and_authorize_resource :myns_advertisement, class: Myns::Advertisement, :through => :myns_dashboard
```

And the ability class is:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, dashboard_id)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can :show, Myns::Dashboard, id: dashboard_id
    can :read, Myns::Advertisement, :myns_dashboard => { :id => dashboard_id }
  end
end
```

When I load the ability for a user in the console and ask if this user can update the advertisement with ID 6, it says "no"

```
user = User.first
ability = Ability.new(user,  1)
advertisement = Myns::Advertisement.find 6
ability.can? :update, advertisement
=> false
```

But when I open my browser, sign in as the User with id 1 and browse directly to http://localhost/myns/dashboards/1/advertisements/6/edit, the site is displayed without any errors. I can edit fields and submit the changes and they are saved in the database.

I'm also able to open http://localhost/myns/dashboards/1/advertisements/new and create new datasets.

So obviously, I've overlooked something... What?

Comment: the first thing that jumps out to me is the no quotes around the [namespace](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#custom-class). You could also try debugging at the controller method level to see if it returns the same as rails console. 

My question I guess also is are there any public methods on this controller? if so why not just tell it to skip those and just simplify it to `load_and_authorize_resource, class: Myns::Dashboard`

Comment: I think because he wants the referent for the `through` statement.

Comment: I delete the CanCanCan Gem from this project and write my own authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override `current_ability` in your ApplicationController to feed that second parameter to your Ability constructor?  I'm not sure how the server version is getting the same information your console example shows.